# Flutter: Error in assigning value to const color

Tags: flutter, dart

```
const color = Colors.red; // no error
const color100 = Colors.red[100]; // error
```

If `Colors.red` is a compile time constant, why `Colors.red[100]` isn't.

Comment: my wild guess is that the overloaded [] operator method in colors.dart (where ColorSwatch is defined, the base class of MaterialColor) is not defined as const in contrast to the normal constructors which are.

Comment: my comment was partly wrong. Colors.red is in fact a static const field which only works because the constructor of MaterialColor is also const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can only assign constant values to a `const` variable.

And the return type of an operator `T1 operator [](T2 i)` isn't/can't be declared as `const`

So you can't do `const a = b[c];`

Like the return type of a function `T1 x(T2 y)` isn't/can't be declared as `const`

So you can't do `const z = x(y);`

Because when you use an operator or a function, you are not creating the return value at the moment of the call, so you are not returning a constant value. That can only be achieved with a constructor.

So you can do `const a = ClassA();` if the constructor of `ClassA` is declared `const`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value of `Colors.red` to a `const` variable because `Colors.red` is a `static const` instance of `MaterialColor`. `MaterialColor` extends `ColorSwatch` which in turn extends `Color`, which is why you can use a `MaterialColor` as a `Color`.

`Colors.red[100]` cannot be assigned to a `const` variable because its value is obtained by applying the `[]` operator defined within `ColorSwatch`:

```
Color operator [](T index) => _swatch[index];
```

Operators are similar to named functions - the main difference is they use a different syntax. Operators and functions cannot use the `const` keyword as of now even if they only return const values, and as such their return values cannot be assigned to `const` variables either.

Comment: What is the meaning of `named functions`? All the functions are named functions, aren't they or you meant `named constructor`?

Comment: I meant functions with an alphanumeric name, unlike operators which could be considered functions that use symbols instead of an alphanumeric name.